# Set ID with Jquery getScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add this script with Jquery getScript, how can I add the attribute ID?

```
$.getScript('https://cdn.asksuite.com/infochat.js?dataConfig=https://control.asksuite.com/api/companies/hotel-latitud-buzios', function () {
 ID --> How to add this
});
```

Script:

```
<script id="script-infochat" src='https://cdn.asksuite.com/infochat.js?dataConfig=https://control.asksuite.com/api/companies/hotel-latitud-buzios'></script>
```

Comment: what ID do you mean?

Comment: This ID: id="script-infochat"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getScript` has no feature that makes that possible.

Instead, create the `script` element using the traditional way (`$('<script></script>', attributeObject)` and append it to your document.

If you have control over the script you are importing, consider using [`currentScript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript) instead of depending on specific IDs.